# How to replace nested python dictionary value from a key as a string format with separated by dots?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

```
a = {
    'user': {
        'username': 'mic_jack',    
        'name': {
            'first': 'Micheal',
            'last': 'Jackson'
        },
        'email': 'micheal@domain.com',

        #...
        #... Infinite level of another nested dict
    }     
}

str_key_1 = 'user.username=john'
str_key_2 = 'user.name.last=henry'
#...
#str_key_n = 'user.level2.level3...leveln=XXX'
```

Let's consider this 'str_key' string, goes with infinite number of dots/levels.

**Expected Output:**

```
a = {
    'user': {
        'username': 'john',     # username, should be replace    
        'name': {
            'first': 'Micheal',
            'last': 'henry'     # lastname, should be replace 
        },
        'email': 'micheal@domain.com',

        ...
        ... # Infinite level of another nested dict
    }     
}
```

I'm expecting the answers for applying 'n' Level of nested key string, rather than simply replacing by `a['user']['username'] = 'John'` statically. Answers must be work for any number of 'dotted' string values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Really feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you saying you want a string for every possible combination of depth through n nested dicts?

Comment: @ruohola I have a 'config' dictionary object in 'config.py'. The user have the option to override this value from 'command line' like (e.g `python run.py env=dev user.name.last=John`)

Comment: @JaiK have you considered that your `config` dictionary could be in a simpler format?

Comment: @ruohola Some time, I want to group them as a single unit, For example, the config for 'Database' are grouped into `db: {'HOST'='X', 'PORT': 8080, 'USERNAME': 'XXX', 'PASSWORD': 'YYY'}`, destination output is grouped into `dest: {'DIR_PATH': '/output', 'FILE_EXT': 'csv'}` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three steps:

1. Separate the key-value pair string into a fully-qualified key and
   value.
2. Split the key into path components.
3. Traverse the dictionary to find the relevant value to update.

Here's an example of what the code might look like:

```
# Split by the delimiter, making sure to split once only
# to prevent splitting when the delimiter appears in the value
key, value = str_key_n.split("=", 1)

# Break the dot-joined key into parts that form a path
key_parts = key.split(".")

# The last part is required to update the dictionary
last_part = key_parts.pop()

# Traverse the dictionary using the parts
current = a
while key_parts:
  current = current[key_parts.pop(0)]

# Update the value
current[last_part] = value
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using this temp. var `current = a`, because of without this assignment also the above code is working. I meant, directly using 'a' instead of 'current'.

Comment: @jai without assignment a will become "{'first': 'Micheal', 'last': 'henry'}"

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a recursive function to accomplish this, assuming your key value strings are all valid:

```
def assign_value(sample_dict, str_keys, value):
  access_key = str_keys[0]

  if len(str_keys) == 1:
    sample_dict[access_key] = value
  else:
    sample_dict[access_key] = assign_value(sample_dict[access_key], str_keys[1:], value)

  return sample_dict
```

The idea is to traverse your `dict` until you hit the lowest `key` and then we assign our new value to that last key;

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  sample_dict = {
      'user': {
          'username': 'mic_jack',    
          'name': {
              'first': 'Micheal',
              'last': 'Jackson'
          },
          'email': 'micheal@domain.com'
      }     
  }

  str_key_1 = 'user.username=john'
  str_keys_1, value_1 = str_key_1.split('=')
  sample_dict = assign_value(sample_dict, str_keys_1.split('.'), value_1)

  print("result: {} ".format(sample_dict))


  str_key_2 = 'user.name.last=henry'
  str_keys_2, value_2 = str_key_2.split('=')
  sample_dict = assign_value(sample_dict, str_keys_2.split('.'), value_2)

  print("result: {}".format(sample_dict))
```

To use the `assign_value` you would need to split your original key to the *keys* and *value* as seen above;

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using exec() and modify your str_key(s), you could do something like:

```
def get_keys_value(string):
    keys, value = string.split("=")
    return keys, value

def get_exec_string(dict_name, keys):
    exec_string = dict_name
    for key in keys.split("."):
        exec_string = exec_string + "[" + key + "]"
    exec_string = exec_string + "=" + "value"
    return exec_string

str_key_1 = "'user'.'username'=john"
str_key_2 = "'user'.'name'.'last'=henry"
str_key_list = [str_key_1, str_key_2]

for str_key in str_key_list:
    keys, value = get_keys_value(str_key) # split into key-string and value
    exec_string = get_exec_string("a", keys) # extract keys from key-string 
    exec(exec_string)

print(a)
# prints {'user': {'email': 'micheal@domain.com', 'name': {'last': 'henry', 'first': 'Micheal'}, 'username': 'john'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_key_1 = 'user.username=john'
str_key_2 = 'user.name.last=henry'

a = {
    'user': {
        'username': 'mic_jack',    
        'name': {
            'first': 'Micheal',
            'last': 'Jackson'
        },
        'email': 'micheal@domain.com',

        #...
        #... Infinite level of another nested dict
    }     
}

def MutateDict(key):
    strkey, strval = key.split('=')[0], key.split('=')[1]
    strkeys = strkey.split('.')
    print("strkeys = " ,strkeys)
    target = a
    k = ""
    for k in strkeys:
        print(target.keys())
        if k in target.keys():
            prevTarget = target
            target = target[k]
        else:
            print ("Invalid key specified")
            return
    prevTarget[k] = strval


MutateDict(str_key_1)

print(a)

MutateDict(str_key_2)

print(a)
```